# issue with mysql LOAD DATA when table has a column that is BIGINT and unique

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

So the table schema looks like:

```
field - type - index

'id' - INT - PRI
'event_id' - BIGINT(20) - UNI
co1 ... colN (no indexes)
```

LOAD DATA command:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'my-file' REPLACE INTO TABLE mydb.mytable (event_id, col1 .. colN)`

and get error:

`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1`

'key 1' refers to the unique key on 'event_id'.

More context: 
 (1) The table is empty at the time of LOAD DATA.
 (2) When I grep for 2147483647 in my source file I get nothing
 (3) 2147483647 is the integer max value
 (4) I am not actually inserting any value in 'id' -- its just auto incrementing
 (5) I am using the 'REPLACE' keyword in the LOAD DATA so even there were dupes, it should know how to deal with them?

This suggest some int overflow issue (ie, I don't think there are any genuine dupes in the source data or in the table), and indeed the values in 'my-file' for 'event_id' are all over the integer max limit. However, the error is odd because 'event_id' column is BIGINT.

As a temporary fix, I dropped the unique index on 'event_id' and the LOAD DATA command worked! The values in 'event_id' were all fine, not truncated or anything. So there is nothing wrong with the table handling the values, but somehow LOAD DATA is checking the uniqueness but as an integer?

Has anyone encountered something similar? Thanks

Comment: please copy a part of the load data file to see how the insert is, and make this query "show create table tablename" (in tablename put the name of the destiny table)

Comment: try this anyway, alter table tablename auto_increment=0;

Answer (score 0):

So what this means is that '2147483647' already exists in that database in a field marked as a key. Just remove the key from that field and you should be fine!

Edit: As stated in your question, event_id is your primary key - you cannot have the same value twice in a primary key.

Best of luck!

Comment: I don't think that is the issue because (I forgot to mention) is that (1) the table is empty at the time of load and (2) grep'ing for 2147483647 in my source file found nothing and (3) 2147483647 happens to be the integer max value

Comment: That's a great point - So you had two values above the max int value, which made two revert to that number. Just set it to a text field.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not the data type,

the thing is that you only have 2 fields and one is PK and the other is UNIQUE, so there is no way that you could have repeated a value.  When you make an insert or load data it's trying to add twice an entry with this value "2147483647", you have several ways to fixed it.

- The first one try to open the file with a text editor and find the repeated value and fixed it, if it's not working try with a mysqldump or phpmyadmin to export the data and edit the file in a text editor.
- Make an export again, if the problem persist try export the data by others methods (mysqldum or phpmyadmin) and re import it
- Try recreating a table without primary keys, you can use this

  create table big_int_test (select * from table1);
  and it will make a copy of the table without the PK, INDEXES and FK.
- You can delete the index and UNIQUE key constraint, import the data, fix the table (delete the repeated values) and re create the PK and UNIQUE KEY (this is a kind of crazy but It could work)

Comment: Hey -- sorry I edited the original question to add two really important pieces of context ... (1) the table is empty at time of load (2) grep'ing the source file for '2147483647' gives me nothing (ie, that doesn't even exist) ... also (3) 2147483647 is the integer max value. I am pretty sure this is some integer max issue and not that there are actually any genuine dupes in the data or table